# Declare Generic method in a "normal" class and its return

Tags: java, generics, comparable, compareto

I need a non-generic class containing a method with two generic parameters . In this method my goal is to compare two generic parameters and return the greater value.  How can I do it?

```
public class generic <T extends Comparable<T>>{

    public T Max( T pv, T sv){
        if(pv.compareTo(sv)>=0){
            return pv;
        }else {
            return sv;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        generic g = new generic();
        System.out.println(g.Max( 2, 7));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(foo, bar));`? Or, some other means... Basically, you can do this with a generic method, there is no need for a generic *class*.

Comment: @AndyTurner "there is no need for a generic *class*" I'm fairly sure they understand that, and didn't want one, but didn't know the syntax to construct it.

Comment: @Michael ok: but the term "generic method" is a good nudge towards [finding the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move it to the method declaration

```
public class Generic {

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> T max( T pv, T sv){
        if (pv.compareTo(sv) >= 0) {
            return pv;
        } else {
            return sv;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Generic g = new Generic();
        System.out.println(g.max(2, 7));
    }
}
```

Also the method could be static, because it does not rely on any state. It would make calling it easier

```
System.out.println(max(2, 7));
```